# Mechanics and structure for an artificial giant creature?

Tags: engineering, materials, robots

I originally wanted to create giant land biological life-forms but the square cube law is limiting me to sauropod body sized creatures so another element of my story is artificially enhanced biological creatures and full robotic creatures.

I am wondering what would be the best internal structure for gigantic creatures, for the question I will just ask about a fully robotic creature.

From a previous question close to the subject, the structure of suspension bridges were mentioned for bone structure, this sounds like an effective way to give the creatures a very stable and strong base structure.

I want to find out what other mechanical elements and structure arrangements could create a strong and stable gigantic creature, the size I am thinking is 50 metres to 200 or more if possible, I can design the creatures of different sizes around the limitations.

I have nanomaterials in my story but I would prefer we keep to known metals and plastics strengths for building the structure, the creatures I have in mind are quadrupedal and will reside on planets with similar gravity and atmosphere as our own.

What are the limitations for a giant robotic creature and what is most efficient mechanical and structural design?

Comment: Most efficient for what? An America's cup class ship is very efficient for racing, but as a cargo is pretty much worthless

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica efficient at imitating a large biological creature and their motion, including not collapsing under our gravity on land.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Gonflable enormé!**

[image: French godzilla]

[Floating monster attacks France](http://www.globaltimes.cn/content/944758.shtml)

Your giant creatures have large interior spaces filled with air.  This method of cheaply (from a biological perspective) increasing size is used in land and water creatures both.  The puffer fish is a fine water example, and bamboo is the classic land example.  You can make a balloon as big as you want!

I propose your gonflables would have pressurized air chambers within their limbs and bodies.  By controlling flow between these chambers they could adjust size and extent, and so move across the land.  They would need to be careful on windy days, possibly eating stones / earth to ballast themselves, or donning heavy but fashionable anklets.

Air is cheap and available but if you wanted to get fancy (and you do!) you could have these creatures electrolyze water and fill themselves with hydrogen.  This would provide a low heat but fairly spectacular mechanism for fire breath or other flaming emissions as the tone of your fiction warrants.

Comment: I did have in mind some biological gas creatures but their safety was an issue, how can I protect the inflatable areas from puncture?

Comment: You could have discrete foam cells, like a foam rubber life preserver.  Or you could have them heal, the way we protect ourselves against puncture.

Comment: oh nice idea, thanks.

Comment: `fill themselves with hydrogen.` Just don't use them in battles, 'cause all I need to take them down is to puncture them with a mass of oxidizer, they already have an impressive amount of fuel in their make. To reduce the weight of a skeleton the size of the Eiffel tower under _normal atmospheric pressure_ one will need lotsa hydrogen. ummm... I feel that a projectile filled with liquefied fluorine may be an overkill, but I'd like to be there - at safe distance! - to see it when it happens.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi that's what I was thinking, I was hoping for more solid structure based ideas but I do like the thought of multiple smaller foam cells, that idea could work for biological creatures too, with light weight armour plated skin to protect.

Comment: @RandySavage each of those foam cells will have walls, walls that will weight something. Compute the buoyancy force of a cell volume worth of hydrogen and see what is the mass of those walls to actually gain a... ummm... apparent loss in weight. With this insight, revisit the [Square cube law - the aerostats edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law) and try to understand why a single uncompartmentalized volume is so much better that zillions of small others that add to the same amount.